# Creating hidden folders

Tags: c#, .net, filesystems

Is there any way that I can programmatically create (and I guess access) hidden folders on a storage device from within c#?

Comment: retagged, as this is not a C# language-specific question

Answer (score 131, accepted):

```
using System.IO; 

string path = @"c:\folders\newfolder"; // or whatever 
if (!Directory.Exists(path)) 
{ 
DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path); 
di.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory | FileAttributes.Hidden; 
}
```

Comment: Now you are the first result on Google.

Answer (score 30):

Yes you can. Create the directory as normal then just set the attributes on it. E.g.

```
DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\SomeDirectory");

//See if directory has hidden flag, if not, make hidden
if ((di.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
{   
     //Add Hidden flag    
     di.Attributes |= FileAttributes.Hidden;    
}
```

Comment: If clause can be reduced to `if (!di.Attributes.HasFlag(FileAttributes.Hidden))`

Answer (score 7):

```
CreateHiddenFolder(string name)  
{  
  DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(name);  
  di.Create();  
  di.Attributes |= FileAttributes.Hidden;  
}
```

Answer (score 4):

```
string path = @"c:\folders\newfolder"; // or whatever 
if (!System.IO.Directory.Exists(path)) 
{ 
    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path); 
    di.Attributes = FileAttributes.Directory | FileAttributes.Hidden; 
}
```

From [here](http://www.csharpfriends.com/Forums/ShowPost.aspx?PostID=54724#54727).

Answer (score -2):

Code to get only Root folders path.

Like If we have C:/Test/
C:/Test/Abc
C:/Test/xyz
C:/Test2/
C:/Test2/mnp

It will return root folders path i.e.
C:/Test/
C:/Test2/

```
            int index = 0;
            while (index < lst.Count)
            {
                My obj = lst[index];
                lst.RemoveAll(a => a.Path.StartsWith(obj.Path));
                lst.Insert(index, obj );
                index++;                    
            }
```

Comment: Code dumps without explanation are rarely useful. Please add some context to this. (Also, you might be interested to know that you've answered a post that's over 6 years old...)