# how to prevent hidden folder from being searched?

Tags: vbscript, hidden, fso

i am new to vbscript but i need to write a vbscript to create a new directory and set it attributes to hidden...
now i want it shouldn't be shown when user searched for the hidden folders.
can someone help how i can achieve this?? 
here is my small code

```
Dim objFSO, objFolder, strDiretory, 

strDirectory = "E:\logs"

Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")




      Set objFolder = objFSO.CreateFolder(strDirectory)

   Set objFolder = objFSO.getFolder(strDirectory)
   objFolder.Attributes = 1
```

Comment: "Hidden" means it's not displayed by default. It doesn't mean it can't be found. Please take a step back and describe the actual problem you're trying to solve instead of what you perceive as the solution. Why shouldn't your users find that folder?

Comment: i am just trying to learn about virus etc how can i use such options adopt by different viruses and trojans etc.... just to find some ways to track them down...

Answer (score 0):

If I remember right, hidden folders use an attribute of 2, not 1. Try the following code in place of yours for setting the attribute:

```
If objFolder.Attributes = objFolder.Attributes AND 2 Then
    objFolder.Attributes = objFolder.Attributes XOR 2
End If
```

Comment: yeah i used 2 i mistakenly posted 1 here.... but windows is showing thz hidden folder if search for hidden folders.... i wanna prevent it from being visible....

Comment: I don't think you are able to do that if you explicitly tell Windows to do a search for hidden folders.

Comment: hmm yeah i was searching for it havent found anything yet.... there could be alternative way??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/500845/how-can-i-hide-a-directory-in-c-sharp-with-a-file-system-driver