# Hidden Folder in Application's file system

Tags: c#

I have an application that on closing, it writes to a log file. BUT I don't really want users to notice it (the file is already readonly). So I just want to hide the folder called "Logs". How can I make the folder hidden?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92376/c-creating-hidden-folders

Comment: why is this file that users will never see valuable?  Why are you creating it?  If you need them to use it,will they be able to find something you hid?  WOuldn't it be better to given them a switch to enable/disable logging when they're having problems?

Comment: Could be (for example!) logging unsuccessful attempts to access unauthorized data..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this by setting the [FileAttributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileattributes.aspx) for the file or directory to include FileAttributes.Hidden.

This can be done via the [DirectoryInfo.Attributes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.attributes.aspx) property for the folder in question.

Answer (score 1):

You can set the `DirectoryInfo` attributes to indicate that it should be hidden.

```
DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory("C:\Logs");  //or whatever 
di.Attributes = di.Attributes | FileAttributes.Hidden;
```

Answer (score 0):

I've assumed a Microsoft environment, given the C# tag. Try:

```
File.SetAttributes(filePath, File.GetAttributes(filePath) | FileAttributes.Hidden);
```