# Start MS DOS command "attrib" as process (C#)

Tags: c#, dos

I'm trying to hide a folder with C# using the MSDOS "attrib" command.

For now i'm able to do that by writing the "attrib" command + arguments in a batch file, running that file using `Process.Start()`,  and then deleting it. I was wondering, can I do that directly from C#?

Here is what i've tryed so far... (the code below doesen't work)

```
    public static void hideFolder(bool hide, string path)
    {
        string hideOrShow = (hide) ? "+" : "-";
        Process.Start("attrib " + hideOrShow + "h " + hideOrShow + "s \"" + path + "\" /S /D");
    }
```

Any help would be appriciated!
Thanx!

Comment: Why aren't you just using File.SetAttributes? http://www.csharp-examples.net/file-attributes/

Comment: becouse then you can still see the files and folders in the window explorer

Comment: possible duplicate of [Hidden Folder in Application's file system](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2268369/hidden-folder-in-applications-file-system)

Comment: @Andrej: If the user has the setting "Show Hidden Files and Folders" turned on, I don't think there is much you can do.

Comment: it's not a duplicate, becouse i want to do this by using the "attrib" command, and not the frameworks methods for hiding

Comment: @0A0D even with the "Show Hidden Files and Folders" turned on - files still do not show up if you use the "attrib" command.. i tryed.. but if you use file.setatributes they show up..

Comment: Try again, mate. You somehow didn't look right. It's the exact same thing.

Comment: @Andrej: Yes they do. They are greyed out. I just tried it.

Comment: @0A0D .. they are greyed out, but they show up.. if i use attrib they do not show at all... try using attrib, then refreshing the directory in which you hid the files

Comment: @Andrej: You are wrong. I just went to the command line and typed `attrib +H C:\test`, then `My Computer > Local Disk (C:)` and the folder is greyed out and does not disappear. The +S you are using is for a System file and it does not make anything disappear either if 'Show Hidden Files and Folders' or 'Show System Files' is on.

Comment: @Andrej: I used `attrib +h +s testfolder` to set a folder as hidden and system. I can still see it grayed out in Windows Explorer. If you have "Show Hidden Files and Folders" turned on, you can see the file. It doesn't matter whether you set the attributes with `attrib` or with the Framework's API. I'm running Windows Server 2008 R2.

Comment: @0A0D - yes, at first it's like that.. but then (from c: - where you see the folder beeing greyed out) refresh the windows explorer... i tried and i don't see the folder in my windows explorer.. or with the dir /p command line from msdos..

Comment: Possible confusion - "Show Hidden Files And Folders" does not show 
System files - they only appear if 'Hide Protected Operating System Files' is unchecked as well.

Comment: @Andrej: Yes, I did that (hit F5) and it still shows.

Comment: @CodeByMidnight: Yes, that's exactly what I meant by 'Show System Files' - I couldn't remember the exact name of the option.

Comment: @CodeByMoonlight - yeah, thanks for clearing that up... @0A0D - guess it was a missunderstanding...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first parameter to Process.Start() needs to be the name of an executable file or document. You'll need to pass in two parameters, like this:

```
Process.Start("attrib.exe", hideOrShow + "h " + hideOrShow + "s \"" + path + "\" /S /D");
```

Also, while attrib.exe will work when called directly, most people will pass this kind of DOS-style command to the command interpreter (which will also work for built-in commands, etc.)

```
Process.Start("cmd.exe", "/c attrib " + restOfTheArguments);
```

Comment: this is what i needed.. tnx very much!

Answer (score 7):

### What you asked for:

```
string hideOrShow = (hide) ? "+" : "-";
Process.Start("cmd /c attrib " + hideOrShow + "h " + hideOrShow + "s \"" + path + "\" /S /D");
```

### What you should do instead:

```
File.SetAttributes(path, FileAttributes.Hidden);
```

Comment: Actually. attrib is C:\Windows\System32\attrib.exe, but your way is still far better.

Comment: @MichaelEdenfield: Oops... it's been so long since DOS that I forgot that! :o

Comment: be a little cautious with the File.SetAttributes() above, this will do two things - clear all the currntly set attributes (system,read-only, etc), and will set Hidden.   I posted a minor change below to demonstrate how to 'mask' in Hidden such that any existing attributes stick while hidden is added.

Answer (score 1):

C# makes this really easy - the idea is you get the files current attributes (File.GetAttributes()),  then you add in the Hidden attribute before calling File.SetAttributes()

check the below out,  it'll make c:\blah hidden

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FileAttributes oldAttributes = File.GetAttributes(@"c:\blah");
    File.SetAttributes(@"c:\blah", oldAttributes | FileAttributes.Hidden);
}
```

to remove the hidden attribute you need to remove the hidden attribute

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    FileAttributes newAttributes = File.GetAttributes(@"c:\blah");
    newAttributes = newAttributes & (~FileAttributes.Hidden);

    File.SetAttributes(@"c:\blah", newAttributes);
}
```

Comment: as i said, i'm using windows 7 (tested in xp too), i have the "Show Hidden Files and Folders" turned on, and this doesen't work for me... BUT, if I use the attrib command, then the files (or folders) are hidden..

Comment: hmm, works for me (just verified) - "Show Hidden Files and Folders" means that you see the hidden file, but it's grayed out.  So if the hidden attribute is applied, and if "Show Hidden Files" is enabled, you should see the file but it should be gray

Comment: am i the only one who doesen't see the files when hidden with attrib? :) i checked i have the "Show Hidden Files" enabled and when i hide the files using attrib, i don't see them...

Comment: could you have some kind of shell extension installed?  perhaps a background changer, theme program, or something like Window Blinds?

Answer (score 0):

What's the error? Why not use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.attributes.aspx ?