# issues on creating a hidden folder

Tags: c#

I want to create a folder and that should be hide, for that i written the code like this

```
 string path = @"E:\newfolder";  
 if (!Directory.Exists(path))
 {
    DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
    if ((di.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
     {  
      di.Attributes |= FileAttributes.Hidden;
     }
 }
```

But still the folder is visible , I dont want to change the properties on windows so what should i have to do

Comment: Did you try to refresh the directory in which it is created?

Comment: Yes i did but still it is visible

Comment: check this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92376/creating-hidden-folders

Comment: how can will store the attributes that i modified

Comment: Check this out its working fine :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/92376/creating-hidden-folders

Comment: I'm not having more knowledge on attributes so please help me sir..

Comment: @Ravi Kanth sir i seen already that page

Comment: Type "dir e:\", then check whether "newfolder" is visible or not. I think it must be invisible. But, in explorer you can see all of the folders (even hidden) if "Hidden items" option is checked.

Comment: the given path format is not supported sir..

Answer (score 0):

Your code is fine. Make sure that "Don't show hidden files, folders or drives" is selected in Folder Options. (Control Panel, clicking Appearance and Personalization, and then clicking Folder Options.)

Or else you can make the folder attributes to hidden and system as follows. Then it will only be visible when you set "Show hidden files, folders or drives" and uncheck "Hide protected operating system files (Recommended)" in Folder Options.

Also your method will not work if the directory is already exists. So I added else part for the if conditional statement to change the attributes of a existing folder.

```
string path = @"E:\newfolder";
if (!Directory.Exists(path))
{
   DirectoryInfo di = Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
   if ((di.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
   {
     di.Attributes = FileAttributes.System|FileAttributes.Hidden;//set attributes to System and Hidden.
   }
}
else
{
   //set attributes if the directory is already exists.
   DirectoryInfo di = new DirectoryInfo(path);
   if ((di.Attributes & FileAttributes.Hidden) != FileAttributes.Hidden)
   {
     di.Attributes = FileAttributes.Hidden;
   }
}
```

Comment: Without changing the properties in Folder options ,any other way is present

Comment: Just to be clear, I was not talking about the properties of the folder you created. (named newfolder) Only if you select "Don't show hidden files, folders or drives" in folder options (As I described above) hidden folders will not be visible.